# what is the point of making variables private?

Tags: javascript, private, public

What is the point of making values private versus public?  It seems like it's just more work on my part...  (this is assuming i'm the only one who will ever use these functions...)

Is there some sort of security concern with this?

```
function att1() {
    this.value = "";
}

function att2() {
    var _value = "";
    this.setValue = function(val){_value=val;}
    this.getValue = function(){return _value;}
}
```

Comment: I'd do it if I needed to validate the variable. If you only wanted an integer in _value then you could parse it on the setValue function.

Comment: IF you have two functions **maybe** you won't see any difference. Imagine you have a _normal_ JS program. Are you **always** sure name you're using for your variable won't conflict with something you function will call? Or with something that called your function?

Comment: In this context, your setter isn't doing any validation, preparation, or dutiful assignment; so there is no difference in public/private.  But, if you wanted to put constraints and not rely/trust the code that is setting the value to do it, that's the power.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input.  I guess it does make the code better / easier to work with by validating/checking the values before it's set...  It's a little annoying when you've got 40+ variables to deal with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private variables are useful in that it ensures you can't break the functionality of a program by modifying them elsewhere in the code.

For instance, suppose you had a variable HP that represented your hit-points in a game. You don't want that to go below zero.

If you simply made the field public

```
var hp;
```

then you could easily make a function that reduces your HP below zero;

```
hp = 100;
hp -= 200;
```

But by "hiding" the field as a private int, you can now write methods that properly adjust hp:

```
function setHP(newHP)
{
    if (newHP < 0)
        newHP = 0;
    hp = newHP;
}
```

meaning that you can't "break" the variable in your code any more (at least, not outside of the class that you defined it!)

Answer (score 2):

Setters and getters for private variables are useful because they allow you to restrict direct access to variables and perform some check of values you want to assign. For example, you have a variable which **has** to be positive. You can provide direct access to it - and it won't give you any guarantee that every piece of code which changes its value will set it to positive value. The better solution will be to provide a `setter` function which will check its argument and, if it's negative, keep and old value of variable (for example), and write something to log.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's useful to have getters and setters for variables. It allows for easy debugging of the get/set operations, just set a breakpoint in the setter and see when and by whom the object state is getting altered. Can't tell you how much headache has this saved me.

Also, you probably don't want to expose all object state to everyone.